# Changing Format_Level, colour_range, transfer_characteristics without re-encoding the file when using FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a file with the following metadata:

```
"Format_Level": "6.2",

"colour_range": "Full",

"colour_range_Source": "Container / Stream",

"transfer_characteristics": "PQ",

"transfer_characteristics_Source": "Container / Stream",
```

I want to change / add the metadata to this - is it possible to change this data without re-encoding the video file? What are the commands I would need?

```
"Format_Level": "5.2",

"colour_range": "Limited",

"colour_range_Source": "Container",

"colour_range_Original": "Full",

"colour_range_Original_Source": "Stream",

"transfer_characteristics": "BT.709",

"transfer_characteristics_Source": "Container",

"transfer_characteristics_Original": "PQ",

"transfer_characteristics_Original_Source": "Stream",
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [h264_metadata](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-bitstream-filters.html#h264_005fmetadata) or [hevc_metadata](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-bitstream-filters.html#hevc_005fmetadata) bitstream filter depending on your format.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -map 0 -c copy -bsf:v h264_metadata=level=5.2:video_full_range_flag=0:transfer_characteristics=1 output.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. All files look normal now.

Comment: Thanks! I was getting washed-out colors after transcode to AV1; that seems to be fixed after creating a temporary file with `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -map 0 -c copy -bsf:v h264_metadata=video_full_range_flag=0 temp.mp4` and using the temporary file as input to the transcoder.